# is there way to use postman request with pre request script in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, postman

I already have created a postman collection with a pre-request script and test is there any way to import those data into the JMeter to perform a load test ??

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the pre-request script is doing.

JMeter's equivalent for the Postman's pre-request script is [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) so if you choose `javascript` as the language theoretically you should be able to re-use your pre-request script in JMeter:

[image]

But be aware that

1. Unlike Postman [JMeter is not a browser](https://jmeter.apache.org/) hence it cannot execute JavaScript so JavaScript support is being performed via [Nashorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) engine and it doesn't support everything
2. If you're using Postman JavaScript API ([`pm.*` object](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#the-pm-object) and friends) - you will need to find equivalents in [JMeter API](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)
3. [The only recommended scripting language for JMeter is Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) so if massive refactoring of the pre-request script is required it worth considering re-writing it in Groovy

Comment: Hi Dimitry, i cant select javascript from the dropdown